# Knockout .js with jQuery UI slider

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js

Say I have the following jQuery UI sliders that are linked to a textbox.

Is it possible to allow the user to enter values in the textbox that are greater than the sliders value (and set the slider to max)?

```
ko.bindingHandlers.slider = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
var options = allBindingsAccessor().sliderOptions || {};
$(element).slider(options);
ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "slidechange", function (event, ui) {
    var observable = valueAccessor();
    observable(ui.value);
});
ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
    $(element).slider("destroy");
});
ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "slide", function (event, ui) {
    var observable = valueAccessor();
    observable(ui.value);
});
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
if (isNaN(value)) value = 0;
$(element).slider("value", value);
}
};
```

In this example: http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/Dt7Ka/12/ I would like to be able to save values over 100 in the textboxes and have the sliders appear at their max value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do with only updating the observable value in your `slidechange` event if the observable's value is less then `options.max`:

```
ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "slidechange", function (event, ui) {
    var observable = valueAccessor();
    var currentMax = $(element).slider("option", "max"); 
    if (observable() <= currentMax)
         observable(ui.value);
});
```

[JSFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/snLk8/3/)

Comment: It is better to use options.max instead of 100.

Comment: var currentMax = $(element).slider("option", "max");
            if (observable() <= currentMax)               
               observable(ui.value);

Comment: @woggles thanks for the comment, hardcoding the 100 was a quick solution. I've updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Put this lines after the line: *if (isNaN(value)) value = 0;* at the binding update function

```
if(value>100){
    $(element).slider("option","max",value);          
}
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Razaz/Qy6jR/4/

It changes the maximum value of the slider to the new value entered in the textbox if the value is greater than 100

Greetings.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this doesn't quite do what I want - I want the range to stay the same.